# Hypersurface in $\mathbb P^n$ containing a linear subspace of dimension $r \geq n/2$ has singular points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to prove that if I have a hypersurface $X = Z(F)$ (where $F \in K[x_0, \dots, x_n]_{d>1}$) which contains a linear subspace of dimension $r \geq n/2$ then there exists singular points on $X$.

What I have thought so far:

A point $p=[y_0, \dots, y_n]$ is singular for $Z(F)$ iff $$ \left( \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x_1} (p), \dots, \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x_n} (p) \right) = 0.$$
$Z(F)$ contains a subspace of dimension $r$ (let's assume without loss of generality it has equations $x_{r+1} = 0, \dots, x_{n} = 0$), so we can rewrite
$$ F = x_{r+1}G_{r+1}+ \dots + x_n G_n,$$
where $G_i \in K[x_0, \dots x_n]_{d-1}0$. The condition for $p$ to be singular becomes
$$ \begin{cases} \sum_{i=r+1}^n y_i \partial_0 G_i (p) = 0,\\
 \vdots \\
 \sum_{i=r+1}^n y_i \partial_r G_i(p)=0,\\
 G_{r+1} + \sum_{i=r+1}^n y_i \partial_{r+1} G_i (p) = 0,\\ \vdots
\\
 G_n + \sum_{i=r+1}^n y_i \partial_n G_i (p) = 0.\end{cases}$$

Why this system of equations should have a non-zero solution $[y_0, \dots, y_n]$ if $r \geq n/2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known fact that, if $s \leq k$, $s$ homogeneous polynomials in $K[x_0, \dots, x_k]$ have a common zero in $\mathbb P^k$ (see for example *Shafarevich, Basic Algebraic Geometry*, Corollary 5, p.71). Taking $s:=n-r$, $k:=r$ gives the thesis.

Answer (score 0):

The statement you want to prove is false: Consider $X := \{ (x_0 :...:x_4) \in \mathbb P^4: x_0 = 0 \}$, $Y := \{ (x_0 :...:x_4) \in \mathbb P^4: x_1 = 0 \}$ two 3-dimensional hyperplanes. The intersection

$$Z:= X \cap Y =\{ (x_0 :...:x_4) \in \mathbb P^4: x_0 = 0, x_1 = 0\} \cong \mathbb P^2$$

is a 2-dimensional subspace of X. We have $n = 4, r = 2 \geq 4/2$, but X is regular, q.e.d.

Comment: Yes thank you, of course the degree of the polynomial $F$ must be $> 1$.

Comment: The statement is false also for degree d > 1: Take X the regular quadric in 4-dimensional projective space defined by x_0**2 + ... + x_4**2 = 0. Take Y as above. Then Z defined as the intersection of X and Y is a 2-dimensional quadric contained in X.

Comment: Yes, what I mean for subspace is *linear* subspace.

Comment: Now the statement is correct, please see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15106/can-projective-hypersurfaces-contain-linear-spaces-how-big?rq=1 and its reference to a paper of Jason Starr.